# how can I customize the way pytest prints objects?

Tags: python, pytest, mongoengine

Is there a way I can control the way pytest creates string representations from objects?

specifically I am using `mongoengine` where the objects of type `Document` are just lazily outputed to console as `"<Document: Documment object>"` and I'd like to create a more meaningful conversion to string (probably utilizing the `Document.to_json()` function )

can I get pytest to call a custom function whenever it needs to print out an object?

Comment: does `Document` implement `__str__` and/or `__repr__`? If not, or if you don't like how they are implemented you could patch them.

Comment: I was thinking same as Jon. You can probably do something like `monkeypatch.setattr(Document, "__repr__", Document.to_json)`.